# Agregar otra carpeta a mi repositorio de GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Tengo un respositorio en GitHub de un clon de Spotify que estuve haciendo. Empece con la parte del front dentro de la carpeta llamada 'sushify', el repo es sobre esa carpeta y ahi hago todos los push etc.
Empece a hacer el servidor en la carpeta 'server', la cual esta por fuera de la carpeta 'sushify' por lo tanto mi repositorio no lo reconoce ni trackea sus cambios.
Quiero que el repositorio este compuesto por dos carpetas: la del server y la de sushify que contiene todo el front, como puedo hacer para que mi repo pase de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a algo asi (pero en lugar de client seria sushify en este caso):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la carpeta `sushify` crea una carpeta `client` y mueve para ahí todo lo que tengas en `sushify` excepto `.gitignore` y `Readme.md`. Ahí mismo crea la carpeta `server` y pon lo que quieras dentro. Luego sube todo. No veo cuál es el problema.

Comment: PD: La carpeta .git es la única que no debes de mover de lugar.

Comment: El movimiento lo debe hacer con `git mv` o, luego de hacerlo, correr un `git rm` de la ruta vieja y luego un `git add` de la nueva para que git vea el movimiento.